# certain page of Flask web app goes down after a couple hours

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am hosting a Flask app with nginx and uWSGI on a CentOS box. After a few hours, one of my pages goes down with a `500 internal server error` Do you see anything jump out at you from my configs below?

My `ers_portal_nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location / { try_files $uri @app; }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal/run_web_uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

My `ers_portal_uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
#user info
uid = metheuser
gid = ers_group

#application's base folder
base = /home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal

#python module to import
app = run_web
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/ers_portal_venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#uwsgi varible only, does not relate to your flask application
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal/logs/%n.log
```

Relevant parts of my `views.py`

```
data_modification_time = None
data = None
def reload_data():
    global data_modification_time, data, sites, column_names
    filename = '/home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal/app/static/' + ec.dd_filename
    mtime = os.stat(filename).st_mtime
    if data_modification_time != mtime:
        data_modification_time = mtime
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = pickle.load(f)
    return data

@a bunch of authentication stuff...

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html",
                           title = 'Main',)

@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    login stuff...

@app.route('/my_table')
@login_required
def my_table():
    print 'trying to access data table...'
    data = reload_data()
    return render_template("my_table.html",
                           title = "Rundata Viewer",
                           sts = sites,
                           cn = column_names,
                           data = data) #  dictionary of data
```

I installed nginx via yum (yesterday)
I am using uWSGI installed in my venv via pip
I am on CentOS 6
I have everything set up very similar to [here](http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/), meaning all the configs are in my app folder and  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is symlinked to.

My uwsgi log shows:

```
Wed Jun 11 17:20:01 2014 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 287] during GET /whm-server-status (127.0.0.1)
IOError: write error
[pid: 9586|app: 0|req: 135/135] 127.0.0.1 () {24 vars in 292 bytes} [Wed Jun 11 17:20:01 2014] GET /whm-server-status => generated 0 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.0 404) 2 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

When its working, the print statement in the `views` "`my_table`" route prints into the log file. But not once it stops working.

Any ideas?